# Querying For Past or Future "Sessions" Given Denormalization

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have the following data structure:

```
users/$uid

memberships/$uid/accepted/{sessionId}

sessions/{sessionId}
```

where a session looks like the following:

```
{
  "organizer": $uid,
  "scheduledTime": 1234567838,
  "title": "someTitle",
  "attendees": {
    $uid
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, I want to query for sessions that are in the past or future for a specific user given their memberships. I first thought of putting the times for each session within the membership of the users attending the session, however that will not scale in the case that there are many members that are part of a session. This is due to the need to update every user's membership if the time of the session changes.

Is there a better way to do this? Do let me know if I need to clarify anything.

***Note*** I do realize that I could move attendees into it's own node.

Comment: Yes, you should (not could: should) flatten the data. Yes, duplication is the idiomatic way to allow the querying you want. This will make your writes slower, but your reads faster.

Comment: With that said I guess I could just put the time in every attendees membership and just update it any time the session changes. I was just wondering if there was a better way.